# How to load ajax pagecontent with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, httpclient

I have a website which has some tables that are loaded into the page when you click on an HTML element. I need exactly this table to process my data further with automation.

The following is what I encountered:
1. I open https://example.com/loan
2. I click on "investment tab" which has a js function attached
3. a get-request to https://example.com/loan/investent is sent that replies with the table.

- When I try to access https://example.com/loan/investment directly, I receive an error 404 - not found
- When I try to first access https://example.com/loan/ then /investment I also receive 404 - not found

-> has anyone an Idea on how to load the content?

here is the javascript that loads the table:

```
click: function() {
        var self = $(this);

        self.addClass(activeCssClass)
            .siblings()
            .removeClass(activeCssClass);

        $cardTabsContentUl.children('li').removeClass(activeCssClass);
        $cardTabsContentUl.children('li:eq('+self.index()+')').addClass(activeCssClass);

        $cardTabsContentUl.css({
            left: -(100 * self.index()) + '%'
        });

        if (self.attr("id") == "investment-tab" && !self.hasClass("loaded")) {
            self.addClass("loaded");
            $.ajax({
                url: window.location.href + "/investment"
                , type: "get"
                , success: function (response) {
                    $("#investment-list")
                        .css("display","none")
                        .html(response)
                        .fadeIn();

                    $("#card-tabs-content ul").css("height","auto");
                    performTooltipInitForBlock();
                    applyBasketOperationEvents.call();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer. Lots of people told me it is not possible since ajax is only possible with java

just add a header to your http request

```
//add referrer (may be unnecessary)
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referrer","https://www.example.com");
//this is the important stuff
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
//here is the request
string responseString = client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.com")).Result;
//remove the headers from default so they arent sent every time
GlobalVar.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("X-Requested-With");
GlobalVar.client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Referrer");
```